TypeError when trying to make predictions using a fitted ForecasterSarimax object in Skforecast
I'm encountering an error when trying to predict using a fitted forecaster object. I've followed this SarimaxForecaster tutorial and I don't get any error. However my dataset in hourly and when I try to predict, I get the following error -
TypeError: Expected index of type <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'> for `last_window`. Got <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'>.


Seems like something to do with a last_window in the function. See reproducible code and full error log below -
# libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from skforecast.Sarimax import Sarimax
from skforecast.ForecasterSarimax import ForecasterSarimax

# dataset
start_date = '2023-01-01'
end_date = '2024-01-01'

date_range = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='D')
qty = np.random.randint(low=10, high=100, size=len(date_range))
data = pd.DataFrame({'date': date_range, 'qty': qty})
data.set_index('date', inplace=True)

end_train = '2023-11-01'

data_train = df.loc[:end_train]
data_test  = df.loc[end_train:]


# changing to series for skforecast
data_train_series = pd.Series(data_train['qty'].values, index=data_train.index, name='qty')
data_test_series  = pd.Series(data_test['qty'].values, index=data_test.index, name='qty')

# sarimax forecaster
forecaster = ForecasterSarimax(
                 regressor=Sarimax(order=(1, 1, 1), seasonal_order=(1, 1, 1, 12))
            )

forecaster.fit(y=data_train_series, suppress_warnings=True)

# predict
predictions = forecaster.predict(steps=len(data_test_series))


Full Error Log -
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/Desktop/School/2024_projects/time_series_feature_engineering/practice/01_bakery_skforecast_quickstart.py:1
----> 1 predictions = forecaster.predict(steps=len(data_test_series))

File ~/Desktop/School/2024_projects/time_series_feature_engineering/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/skforecast/ForecasterSarimax/ForecasterSarimax.py:363, in ForecasterSarimax.predict(self, steps, last_window, last_window_exog, exog)
    359 # Needs to be a new variable to avoid arima_res_.append when using 
    360 # self.last_window. It already has it stored.
    361 last_window_check = last_window if last_window is not None else self.last_window
--> 363 check_predict_input(
    364     forecaster_name  = type(self).__name__,
    365     steps            = steps,
    366     fitted           = self.fitted,
    367     included_exog    = self.included_exog,
    368     index_type       = self.index_type,
    369     index_freq       = self.index_freq,
    370     window_size      = self.window_size,
    371     last_window      = last_window_check,
    372     last_window_exog = last_window_exog,
    373     exog             = exog,
    374     exog_type        = self.exog_type,
    375     exog_col_names   = self.exog_col_names,
    376     interval         = None,
    377     alpha            = None,
    378     max_steps        = None,
    379     levels           = None,
    380     series_col_names = None
    381 )
    383 # If not last_window is provided, last_window needs to be None
    384 if last_window is not None:

File ~/Desktop/School/2024_projects/time_series_feature_engineering/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/skforecast/utils/utils.py:643, in check_predict_input(forecaster_name, steps, fitted, included_exog, index_type, index_freq, window_size, last_window, last_window_exog, exog, exog_type, exog_col_names, interval, alpha, max_steps, levels, series_col_names)
    638 _, last_window_index = preprocess_last_window(
    639                            last_window   = last_window.iloc[:0],
    640                            return_values = False
    641                        ) 
    642 if not isinstance(last_window_index, index_type):
--> 643     raise TypeError(
    644         (f"Expected index of type {index_type} for `last_window`. "
    645          f"Got {type(last_window_index)}.")
    646     )
    647 if isinstance(last_window_index, pd.DatetimeIndex):
    648     if not last_window_index.freqstr == index_freq:

TypeError: Expected index of type <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'> for `last_window`. Got <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'>.




I encountered the same error and could find the reason in the docstring of the preprocess_last_window() function. If the frequency of your DatetimeIndex is not specified, this function will convert the DatetimeIndex into a RangeIndex, hence the error message that a DatetimeIndex was expected but a RangeIndex provided. In my opinion quite a misleading error message since you actually provided a pd.Series with a DateTimeIndex. If you add the following line of code before end_train = '2023-11-01' it should work.
data.index = pd.date_range(start=data.index[0], end=data.index[-1], freq='D')

